# How to order stack bar based on cumulative value in each group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a geom_bar with the stack order depending on the cumulative value of each group in each bar. therefore, each bar should have a different order. Here is a reproducible example

```
set.seed(8)

#create dataframe
name <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "aa")
group <- c("1","1","1","2","2", "2", "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2")
subgroup <- c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C")
value <- runif(26, min = 0, max = 10)

df <- data.frame(name, group, subgroup,value)

#plot
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=group, y=value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(fill=reorder(subgroup, value)))
```

The latter results in the following plot:
[image]

Note that it is clear that the B subgroup represents a higher value than C in group 1, but it is plotted above C. I want that, for each group, the subgroups are ordered based on their cumulative value in the group. Does anybody know how to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally a best practice with bar charts is that your factor orders be consistent in each bar. So you can re-order the factor levels to have it always sort A - B - C, or C - A - B, but that will be consistent across all bars. Because of that, I don't know that ggplot will easily handle what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by precalculating the counts and using `geom_tile` instead of `geom_bar`. This way will work automatically with any number of groups and subgroups without manual intervention.

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  count(group, subgroup, wt = value) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  arrange(group, -n) %>%
  mutate(middle = cumsum(n) - n/2) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%

  ggplot(aes(group, fill = subgroup)) +
  geom_tile(aes(y = middle, height = n), width = 0.9)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach using `geom_col()` with filtered data:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(group, subgroup) %>% 
  summarise(helper = sum(value)) %>% 
  mutate(ordering = row_number()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = helper, fill = reorder(subgroup, ordering))) + 
  geom_col(data = . %>% filter(group == 1), position=position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_col(data = . %>% filter(group == 2), position=position_stack()) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend("ordering"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

And another option would be to use the `group` aes. To this end first aggregate your data and arrange your data by group and (cumulated) value as in the approach by @JonSpring. Afterwards you could add a helper column as the interaction of `group` and `subgroup` and set the order via `forcats::fct_inorder`. This helper column could then be mapped on the `group` aes to set the order of the stack:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- df |>
  count(group, subgroup, wt = value) |> 
  arrange(group, n) |> 
  mutate(group_aes = forcats::fct_inorder(paste(group, subgroup, sep = ".")))

# plot
ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = group, y = n, group = group_aes)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = subgroup))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using a new column with the cumulative values and then use fct_reorder to order the stacks.

see example below:

```
df %>%
   group_by(group,subgroup) %>% 
   mutate(csum = cumsum(value)) %>% 
   ggplot()+
   aes(x = group, y = csum)+
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = fct_reorder(subgroup, csum)))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWrzz.png)